# Run scala script with play framework classpath?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I want to run a scala script with the same libraries available as in play framework.

I know that I can set the classpath for the script like this:

`scala -cp "/path_to_play/play_2.10/2.1.3/jars/play_2.10.jar" my_script.scala`

But play has a lot of dependencies (I just printed it's classpath and it's like 50 different directories) and I hope I don't have to add them all in this line. Is there any way to run the script, so to say with the context of play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this from a play project and use the play console.

- create a new play project and go to the created folder
- launch the play console (just type `play` from your shell)
- from the play console, launch the scala console with the `console` command

You can then load a specific scala file using `:load`. Ex :

`scala> :load /path/to/my_script.scala`

Comment: aha, perfect! I knew about `play console`, but I didn't know how to run the script with it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some analogue to this with Play 2.3 where they moved away from the `play` command to using `activator`?

Comment: @Rich As far as I know, the `play` command is just a wrapper around `sbt`, so you can probably use `sbt` instead.